# Robocopy /if (Include Files) syntax does not follow /xf syntax

Tags: cmd, robocopy

I am trying to use the /if (Include Files) flag for robocopy to provide an array list of all the files I would like to copy.

I successfully did this when setting the source directory just 1 level up (e.g. C:\Documents\Folder), and providing just the filename in the array after /if (e.g /if file1).

However, when I try to set the source directory 2 levels up (e.g. C:\Documents) and pass the entire filepath into /if (e.g if/ C:\Documents\Folder\file1 [no extension on these files]), the robocopy will not recognise the entire filepath as a valid parameter. I tried with just one filepath instead of an array, and multiple ways of inputting this such as with double quotes around the filepath, but still errored with invalid parameter.

To test, I tried to do the opposite with /xf, and the robocopy then excluded this file successfully.

Is this a limitation of the /if flag for robocopy?

```
robocopy C:\Documents D:\Documents /e /tee etc... /if "C:\Documents\Folder\file1"
```

Thanks.

Comment: why is powershell tagged to this post ? If your post does not have anything to do with powershell, please remove unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 1):

The `/if` option is for creating robocopy jobs. It supports only filters, not paths. So you could do:

```
robocopy C:\Documents D:\Documents /e /if *.pdf /save:myjob
```

The robocopy syntax allows specifying file names to copy, but not paths:

```
robocopy C:\Documents\Folder D:\Documents\Folder file1 file2
```

(Note: The filenames specified here and with the `/if` option are combined.)

If your files all reside in the same folder, you can just specify all their names. If they are in different folders, you have to run the command for each folder.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response! So *.pdf wouldn't work with these files as they have no extension. My original robocopy was using the source as folder which contained subset 1 of files and would work like you described in the latter part of your response. However, if i wanted to copy both subset 1 in folder 1 and subset 2 in folder 2, like you said it won't work. At least that answers my question - I couldn't find any /if documentation anywhere!

Comment: @Spl0stace I made a small edit. Apparently the option is used for jobs, but also works without. I think this is simply not the use case for robocopy, since it is designed to copy directories. Try using powershell's `Copy-Item` for arrays of filenames.

Comment: Ah okay I see. Yeah, I understand that robocopy is conventionally designed to copy directories. However I managed to pass an array in of just filenames, not filepaths, and it successfully only copied over those 500 out of 2000 files. A confusing one! Thanks for the Copy-Item suggestion, I'll take a look at that. I was advised to use RC as it preserves file metadata so will need to check whether that's the same for Copy-Item